# How to get iPhone calendar event reminder on Apple-Watch

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-watch

Our requirement is to get notification of the iPhone calendar event(set via any app or directly) on Apple-Watch. Is there any way it can be tested by using iPhone/Watch simulators via xcode.

For example,

I've an app which sets the calendar event from within the app on iPhone. Now if I sync my Apple Watch with this iPhone, will it sync all my calendar events on Apple Watch and will it be notified on watch itself? And if this is possible then is there any way to test it using simulators.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not going to work in a simulator to my knowledge. If the event and the alert are being scheduled properly, the calendar app will push the notification to the watch as it sees fit. Run it on a real phone and if you get a calendar alert on the lock screen when you expect it, it will work on the watch all by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't test it on simulator correctly. It is better to test it on a real Apple Watch and iPhone.

Of course, you need an active iOS Developer Program license to do that.